# How can I save the original value of a data attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that I'm using with a quantity input. When the quantity changes I update the data attribute with the new value.

The problem is that when the data attribute is changed, the next iteration of the change is being based off the changed value not the original value.

```js
$(".inc").click(function(){
  service = $(this).closest(".service-option-card");
  let quantity = getCurrentQuantity(service);
  let newQuantity = quantity+1;
  setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);

  updatePrice(newQuantity, service);
});

    
    
$(".dec").click(function(){
  service = $(this).closest(".service-option-card");
  let quantity = getCurrentQuantity(service);
  let newQuantity = quantity-1;

  if(newQuantity <= 0) {
    let newQuantity = 0
    setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  } else {
    setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  }

  updatePrice(newQuantity, $(this).closest(".service-option-card"));
});



function getCurrentQuantity(service) {
  let quantity_str = service.find(".quantity").val();
  quantity_num = Number(quantity_str);
  return quantity_num;
}



function setNewQuantity(quantity, service) {
  service.find(".quantity").val(quantity);
}


function updatePrice(quantity, service) {
  var price = parseInt(service.find(".price").val().replace(/,/g, ""));
  var total = quantity * price;

  if(total < 0) {
    total = 0;
  }

  newPrice = numberFormat(total);
  service.find(".option-price").html("$" + newPrice);

  var monthly = service.data('monthly');
  newMonthly = monthly * quantity;
  console.log(newMonthly);

  updateReceiptMonthly(service, newMonthly);
}

function updateReceiptMonthly(service, newMonthly) {
  service.data('monthly', newMonthly);
}



// Number format

function numberFormat(nStr)
{
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="service-option-card" data-monthly="10">

  <input style="display: none;" class="price" value="50">                                           

  <p class="option-price">$50</p>

  <div class="quantity">
    <button class="btn btn-quantity dec">-</button>
      <input class="quantity-input quantity" value="1">
    <button class="btn btn-quantity inc">+</button>
  </div>

</div>



<div class="col-md-6 services-total-side">  
  <div class="calculated-totals">
    <p class="cost-title">Monthly Cost:</p>
    <p class="monthly-cost">$0</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you run the above snippet, you can see the `console.log` is incrementing 10 > 20 > 60 > 240 and so on. this is because when I update the `data-monthly` attribute on my `service-option-card` its then multiplying the NEW value by the quantity. What I would like is for it to multiply by the ORIGINAL value of 10 so the `console.log` should be 10 > 20 > 30 > 40 and so on. I cant just put 10 in because the values change in my application for diffrent service option cards.

Comment: Why don't you just stop updating `data-monthly` and remove your `updateReceiptMonthly` function? Am I missing something where you need to update it for future calculations?

Comment: I did my best to get my little app working in stack overflow, but the reason I'm trying to update the data-monthly value is to update the bottom section `Monthly Cost:` to reflect the monthly payments that a client would be making if they needed 6 of the selected service

Comment: I have an idea: what if you just copied `data-monthly` into a *new* attribute, and just don't change the new attribute. Then you will have the original value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another property with the same value, but then keep this value the same. Then you'll always have the original base value to use:

```js
$(".inc").click(function(){
  service = $(this).closest(".service-option-card");
  let quantity = getCurrentQuantity(service);
  let newQuantity = quantity+1;
  setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);

  updatePrice(newQuantity, service);
});
    
$(".dec").click(function(){
  service = $(this).closest(".service-option-card");
  let quantity = getCurrentQuantity(service);
  let newQuantity = quantity-1;

  if(newQuantity <= 0) {
    let newQuantity = 0
    setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  } else {
    setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  }

  updatePrice(newQuantity, $(this).closest(".service-option-card"));
});



function getCurrentQuantity(service) {
  let quantity_str = service.find(".quantity").val();
  quantity_num = Number(quantity_str);
  return quantity_num;
}



function setNewQuantity(quantity, service) {
  service.find(".quantity").val(quantity);
}


function updatePrice(quantity, service) {
  var price = parseInt(service.find(".price").val().replace(/,/g, ""));
  var total = quantity * price;

  if(total < 0) {
    total = 0;
  }

  newPrice = numberFormat(total);
  service.find(".option-price").html("$" + newPrice);
  // now using original value here
  var monthly = service.data('base-monthly');
  newMonthly = monthly * quantity;
  console.log(newMonthly);

  updateReceiptMonthly(service, newMonthly);
}

function updateReceiptMonthly(service, newMonthly) {
  service.data('monthly', newMonthly);
}



// Number format

function numberFormat(nStr)
{
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="service-option-card" data-monthly="10" data-base-monthly="10">

  <input style="display: none;" class="price" value="50">                                           

  <p class="option-price">$50</p>

  <div class="quantity">
    <button class="btn btn-quantity dec">-</button>
      <input class="quantity-input quantity" value="1">
    <button class="btn btn-quantity inc">+</button>
  </div>

</div>



<div class="col-md-6 services-total-side">  
  <div class="calculated-totals">
    <p class="cost-title">Monthly Cost:</p>
    <p class="monthly-cost">$0</p>
  </div>
</div>
```